# Takes a second to lock the screen

Tags: lock-screen, time

When I lock the screen (doesn't matter if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or select "Lock" from the menu) to lock the screen, it takes about a second before the screen goes black. This is quite annoying as I lock whenever I leave my office, and since upgrading to 16.04 I have to stop in my tracks to make sure the screen has actually locked.

Any idea on how to fix this?

I'm running Metacity flashback desktop, if that's of any help.

Comment: Is 1 second too much?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing the fading of the screen with the screen not getting locked. The moment you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, you screen is already locked, even if the screen takes a second to fade as a "cinematic effect". I verified this by repeatedly pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> right after <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to attempt to open as many terminals as I can but alas, no new terminals ever opened when I later unlocked my screen to check.

Note: It looks like the screen in GNOME Flashback (Metacity) doesn't fade. Instead, after being locked, it stays on for a second and then turns black. However, the screen is still locked even if it lingers around for that one second.

Comment: That's interesting, because I don't get any cinematic fading effect. It just stays like before, then a second or so later, it goes black.

Comment: Interesting. Is the lock still instantaneous? Or can you actually still do things after hitting Ctrl + Alt + L?

Comment: The lock itself is instantaneous; it's just the blanking out of the screen that's delayed.

Comment: @gablin Ah that is fine then. You don't have to wait for your screen to lock anymore.